# Libgdx grain / noise effect

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, effect

I'm facing a problem achieving a cinema like grain effect for my background in the game (using libgdx). Something important on that: The grain or noise effect should be not static.

I have had different ideas how to do that:
1. Just render another img with some noise / grain effect with less alpha over the first one.
That works actually nearly just as i wanted.

```
// Draw level Background
batch.disableBlending();
batch.begin();
batch.draw(lvlCreator.getBackgroundTexture(), 0, 0, lvlCreator.getBackgroundWidth() / 3, lvlCreator.getBackgroundHeight() / 3, 
            0, 0, 4144, 2000, false, false);
batch.end();

// Draw noise
batch.enableBlending();
batch.begin();
Color c = batch.getColor();
batch.setColor(c.r, c.g, c.b, .1f);
batch.draw(Assets.noiseAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true), 0, 0, 0, 0, 400, 400, 1, 1, 0);
```

2.Using some sort of Shader. However my Shader knowledge is kinda poor. So my question here is if there are some build-in shaders i can use for that. Or do I have to implement my own shader?

3.Since I'm working with libgdx I hoped to achieve that with some libs from it. But if someone knows another lib that could help me here I would love it.

So just tell me whats best practise here and maybe an example if possible. :)

Comment: You might check out https://github.com/manuelbua/libgdx-contribs/tree/master/postprocessing maybe the CRT-Monitor shader might be of use for you.